# Invoke: how can I assign UI obj from BackgroundWorker? C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety, backgroundworker, picturebox

Here is the core of my code. I've tried Invoke every which way to China, but I always get the same big red X and an ObjectDisposed exception on Form1. (Edited out unrelated code for brevity.)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using KnownColorsPalette;

namespace Color_Visualizer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static CultureInfo m_culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        FastPixel m_fp; // FastPixel encapsulates 
                        // Bitmap.LockBits() funcs & data

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            double fAngle, fRadius, d;
            Point3D vU, vV;
            Point pLocation = new Point();

            do
            {
                m_pNormal = Coord.Plane.Normal;

                fAngle = Math.Atan2(m_pNormal.y, m_pNormal.x);
                fRadius = Math.Sqrt(m_pNormal.x * m_pNormal.x + m_pNormal.y * m_pNormal.y);
                fAngle += fSpeed * 180 / Math.PI;
                m_pNormal.x = Math.Cos(fAngle) * fRadius;
                m_pNormal.y = Math.Sin(fAngle) * fRadius;

                m_fp.Lock();
                m_fp.Clear(Color.Black);
                foreach (FoundColors fc in m_lColors.Values)
                {
                    vU = new Point3D(Coord.U);
                    d = dist(fc.pt, ref vU);
                    vV = Coord.V;
                    vV.mult(d);

                    pLocation.X = (int)(m_midHoriz + vU.norm());
                    pLocation.Y = (int)(m_midVert + vV.norm());
                    m_fp.SetPixel(pLocation, fc.color);
                }
                m_fp.Unlock();
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.Image = m_fp.Bitmap; });
            } while (true);
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            CoordinateSystem.AssignMe(this);
        }

        void ReadColors() // I saved all of Wikipedia's 1200+ named colors
        {                 // as a text file.
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadColors();

            Point3D p = new Point3D(127.5, 127.5, 127.5);
            foreach (FoundColors fc in m_lColors.Values)
                fc.pt = fc.color - p; // My Point3D class has 
                           // implicit operator casts to and
                           // from Color.

            Coord = new CoordinateSystem(new Plane(new Point3D(-127.5, -127.5, -127.5), new Point3D(-1, 0, 0)));
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        double fSpeed = 5;
        Point3D m_pNormal = new Point3D();

        double m_fDist, m_fDot;
        public double dist(Point3D pt, ref Point3D vU)
        {
            double c1 = pt.dot(vU);
            double c2 = vU.dot(vU);
            double b = c1 / c2;
            vU.mult(b);
            //m_fDot = pt.dot(Coord.Normal);
            m_fDist = pt.norm(pt - vU);
            return m_fDist;
        }

        double m_midHoriz, m_midVert;
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_midHoriz = pictureBox1.Width / 2;
            m_midVert = pictureBox1.Height / 2;
            m_fp = new FastPixel(new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
        }
    }
}
```

This is just support code, not central to my question:
Sorting.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using KnownColorsPalette;

namespace Color_Visualizer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static ColorComp m_compClr = new ColorComp();
        public static NameComp m_compName = new NameComp();
        SortedList<Color, FoundColors> m_lColors = new SortedList<Color, FoundColors>(m_compClr);
        SortedList<string, FoundColors> m_lColorByName = new SortedList<string, FoundColors>(m_compName);

        [DebuggerDisplayAttribute("{name}, R={color.R}, G={color.G}, B={color.B}")]
        class FoundColors
        {
            public Color color = Color.Empty;
            public string name = "";
            public CIELab_Color cLab;
            public Point3D pt;
            public List<int> lClosest = new List<int>();
            public int nFarthest;
            public FoundColors(FoundColors fc)
            {
                color = fc.color;
                name = fc.name;
                cLab = new CIELab_Color(fc.cLab.CIE_L, fc.cLab.CIE_a, fc.cLab.CIE_b);
                lClosest.AddRange(fc.lClosest);
                nFarthest = fc.nFarthest;
            }
            public FoundColors() { }
        }


        struct sort
        {
            public double dist;
            public int index;
            public sort(double _d, int _i) { dist = _d; index = _i; }
        }

        class DistComp : IComparer<sort>
        {
            int IComparer<sort>.Compare(sort x, sort y)
            {
                if ((object)x == null)
                    if ((object)y == null)
                        return 0;
                    else
                        return -1;

                if ((object)y == null) return 1;

                if (x.dist > y.dist) return -1;

                return 1;
            }
        }


        public class NameComp : IComparer<string>
        {
            int IComparer<string>.Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                if ((object)x == null)
                    if ((object)y == null)
                        return 0;
                    else
                        return -1;

                if ((object)y == null) return 1;

                return x.CompareTo(y);
            }
        }

        public class ColorComp : IComparer<Color>
        {
            int IComparer<Color>.Compare(Color x, Color y)
            {
                if ((object)x == null)
                    if ((object)y == null)
                        return 0;
                    else
                        return -1;

                if ((object)y == null) return 1;

                if (x.R > y.R)
                    return -1;
                else if (x.R < y.R)
                    return 1;
                else if (x.G > y.G)
                    return -1;
                else if (x.G < y.G)
                    return 1;
                else if (x.B > y.B)
                    return -1;
                else if (x.B < y.B)
                    return 1;

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly some more support code, CoordinateSystem.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Color_Visualizer
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        class CoordinateSystem
        {
            const int MAX = 256;
            const double PlaneWidth = 600;

            static Form1 Me;
            static Point3D axisZ = new Point3D(0, 0, 1);
            static Point3D axisY = new Point3D(0, 1, 0);
            private Plane m_plane = new Plane(new Point3D(128, 128, 128), new Point3D(-128, 0, 0));
            private Point3D m_pV = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
            private Point3D m_pU = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
            private double m_fInc;

            public CoordinateSystem(Plane axAxis)
            {
                m_fInc = PlaneWidth / Me.ClientSize.Height;
                Plane = axAxis;
            }
            public static void AssignMe(Form1 form) { Me = form; }
            public Point3D U { get { return m_pU; } protected set { m_pU = value; } }
            public Point3D V { get { return m_pV; } protected set { m_pV = value; } }
            public Point3D Normal { get { return m_plane.Normal; } set { m_plane.Normal = value; } }
            static double COSerror = 0.99619469809174553229501040247389;

            public Plane Plane
            { 
                get { return m_plane; }
                set {
                    m_plane = value;
                    if (m_plane.dot(axisZ) > COSerror)
                        U = U.cross(m_plane, axisY);
                    else
                        U = U.cross(m_plane, axisZ);
                    U.div(U.norm());
                    V = U.cross(U, m_plane);
                    V.div(V.norm());
                }
            }
        }

        [DebuggerDisplayAttribute("x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}")]
        public class Point3D
        {
            public double x, y, z;

            public Point3D(double _x, double _y, double _z) { x = _x; y = _y; z = _z; }
            public Point3D(Point3D p) { x = p.x; y = p.y; z = p.z; }
            public Point3D() { x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; }
            public bool Equals(Point3D p) { return x == p.x & y == p.y & z == p.z; }
            public override bool Equals(object obj) { return Equals((Point3D)obj); }
            public static bool operator ==(Point3D p1, Point3D p2) { return p1.Equals(p2); }
            public static bool operator !=(Point3D p1, Point3D p2) { return !p1.Equals(p2); }
            public static Point3D operator -(Point3D e, Point3D s) { return new Point3D(e.x - s.x, e.y - s.y, e.z - s.z); }
            public static Point3D operator +(Point3D e, Point3D s) { return new Point3D(e.x + s.x, e.y + s.y, e.z + s.z); }
            public static Point3D operator *(double m, Point3D v) { return new Point3D(m * v.x, m * v.y, m * v.z); }
            public static Point3D operator *(Point3D v, double m) { return new Point3D(v.x / m, v.y / m, v.z / m); }
            public static Point3D operator /(double m, Point3D v) { return new Point3D(m * v.x, m * v.y, m * v.z); }
            public static Point3D operator /(Point3D v, double m) { return new Point3D(v.x / m, v.y / m, v.z / m); }
            public static implicit operator Color(Point3D p) { return Color.FromArgb((int)p.x, (int)p.y, (int)p.z); }
            public static implicit operator Point3D(Color c) { return new Point3D(c.R, c.G, c.B); }
            //public override int GetHashCode()
            //{
            //    unchecked
            //    {
            //        var hash = new SpookyHash();
            //        hash.Update(x);
            //        hash.Update(y);
            //        hash.Update(z);
            //        return hash.Final().GetHashCode();
            //    }
            //}

            // dot product (3D) which allows vector operations in arguments
            public double dot(Point3D u, Point3D v) { return u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y + u.z * v.z; }
            public double dot(Point3D u) { return u.x * x + u.y * y + u.z * z; }
            public double norm(Point3D v) { return Math.Sqrt(dot(v, v)); }     // norm = length of  vector
            public double norm() { return Math.Sqrt(dot(this, this)); }     // norm = length of  vector
            public double dist(Point3D u, Point3D v) { return norm(u - v); }         // distance = norm of difference
            public double dist(Point3D u) { return norm(this - u); }
            public Point3D cross(Point3D u, Point3D v) { return new Point3D(u.y * v.z - u.z * v.y, u.z * v.x - u.x * v.z, u.x * v.y - u.y * v.x); }
            public Point3D cross(Point3D u) { return new Point3D(u.y * z - u.z * y, u.z * x - u.x * z, u.x * y - u.y * x); }
            public void add(Point3D p) { x += p.x; y += p.y; z += p.z; }
            public void mult(double m) { x *= m; y *= m; z *= m; }
            public void div(double m) { x /= m; y /= m; z /= m; }
        }


        class Plane : Point3D
        {
            Point3D m_pNormal;

            public Plane(Point3D pOrigin, Point3D pNormal) : base(pOrigin) { m_pNormal = pNormal; }
            public Plane(Point3D p) : base(p) { }
            public Plane(double x, double y, double z) : base(x, y, z) { }
            public Point3D Normal { get { return m_pNormal; } set { m_pNormal = value; } }
            public double PointToPlane(Point3D p) { return p.dot(Normal); }
        }


        private CoordinateSystem m_coordSys;
        private CoordinateSystem Coord
        {
            get { return m_coordSys; }
            set { m_coordSys = value; }
    }
}
```

Only the 1st code segment is genuinely relevant to the question, but I know someone will ask for it, so I included much of the supporting code.

Note that I have also tried such things as diverse as the ProgressChanged event (after enabling it in Properties of course) and various forms of delegates. This use to be a fairly simple matter with old delegates, but I spent 10 hours today with no success, and I almost never fail to find working code examples, even if I have to wade thru dozens of inferior answers. There is an utter profusion of contradictory answers to this question depending on the date of the post and the kind of approach suggested.

Comment: On which line exactly does it crash?

Comment: On the Invoke, for reasons I don't understand, the error occurs in the iteration of the worker thread. In other cases such as ProcessChanged I know there is a "race condition", before the Bitmap is fully copied another attempt at LockBits is made, because ProcessChanged events return immediately before the assignment is finished.

Comment: Delegates fail because they now must call static functions, so the PictureBox is inaccessible, unless I man-handled the Designer code and declare the PictureBox static too, which sounds unwise to me....

Comment: `Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.Image = m_fp.Bitmap; });` worked fine to me. Make sure `m_fp.Bitmap` contains a valid bitmap. The `Big Red X Of Doom` seems to indicate it is not valid.

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I run it from a RunWorkerCompleted event. So that can't be it. It looks the only viable option anyone has given me is to use RunWorkerCompleted, and set a timer to initiate another RunAsync. A hacker kludge answer is the best anyone can come up with? Stackoverflow.com consistently has the answer to my hardest problems over the last 2 years, but you completely dropped the ball this time.

Answer (score 0):

The Invoke method does work if I immediately Thread.Sleep() for 200ms. Haven't tested the lower limit, but it won't be consistent across machines, so reporting it won't be informative.

Answer (score 0):

Update this code

```
...
m_fp.Unlock();
var capturedBitmap = m_fp.Bitmap.Clone();
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.Image = capturedBitmap; });
...
```

You are probably getting the red x because you are modifying the bitmap as you assign it to the picture box.  Clone the bitmap so you are not playing with the one in your picturebox.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Braaten!!